# Primefaces resetinput in cancel button hanging other tabs

Tags: primefaces

I have got an issue with primefaces resetinput. When I press this cancel button all of my other Tabs just hanged. I am using primefaces 3.5.

```
        <p:commandButton id="cancelMainButton" process="@this"
             value="#{bundle.Cancel}" update=":ss_form:ss_tabView:main_tab"
             actionListener="#{eccmServiceSpecController.cancelServiceSpec}"
            icon="ui-icon-cancel">
            <p:resetInput target=":ss_form"/>
        </p:commandButton>


    **Controller**  
    @Named("eccmServiceSpecController")
    @SessionScoped

    public void cancelServiceSpec(ActionEvent event) {
        eccmServiceSpec = ejbFacade.findByServiceSpec(eccmServiceSpec);
        this.setSelected(eccmServiceSpec);
    }

    **Facade** Statefull session bean with Extended mode.
public EccmServiceSpec findByServiceSpec(EccmServiceSpec eccmServiceSpec){
    this.getEntityManager().detach(eccmServiceSpec);
    eccmServiceSpec = this.find(eccmServiceSpec.getServSpecId());
    eccmServiceSpec = this.getEntityManager().merge(eccmServiceSpec);
    return eccmServiceSpec;
}
```

Thanks for your reply. I have added my controller and Facade please look at this. I shall be thankful to you.

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information for us to debug. What do you mean by hanging? Have you looked at the processor to figure out if anything is using up the processor? Could you provide the backing bean so we can see if maybe your actionListener has an infinite loop in it?

Comment: I have fixed the issue by making the commandbutton ajax="false".

Comment: I have also removed the resetInput.